# How do you do a line break in a Servlet response

Tags: java, servlets, response, line-breaks

In my Servlet response, I would like to perform a line break for each println call.  Currently the response text shows up all on one line (i.e. "first line second line").  I have experimented with "\n" and setting the setContentType to "text/html" with <br/> to no avail.  Please advise.

**Here is my test code:**

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
 PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
 pw.println("first line");
 pw.println("second line");
}

Comment: return a String object then you can make a line break.

Comment: I believe this is what you mean ...
String s = new String("first line");
pw.println(s);
s = "second line";
pw.println(s);
This outputs both lines on the same line with no line break.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.  I had to do the following:

1. In the JQuery call in your jsp file, you need to specify .html (i.e. $('#div').html(responseText);) and not .text
2. In the Servlet, set response content type to response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8") and not "text/plain"
3. Add 
    to each println statement (e.g. pw.println("first line<br/>") where pw is the PrintWriter object)

Comment: That wouldn't be sufficient by itself. Line breaks are ignored in HTML. You would have to send a `<br>`.

Comment: Sorry, corrected my last post, had to include &lt;br/&gt;